# Profiling on Android with pg option

Tags: android, gcc, android-ndk, profiling

I'm using latest version of NDK `android-ndk-r8b`
I have some files that were builded via Android compiler from NDK.  `i686-android-linux-gcc`
And now i want to profile these files.
I tried to rebuild it with `-pg` option, but I received an error:

```
/tmp/ccixJFcx.o: In function `main':
test1.C:(.text+0x17): undefined reference to `mcount'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I want to try to use `i686-android-linux-gprof` but without successfully compiling with `-pg` option I cannot do it.

For example let the sources of test1.C be:

```
int main()
{
   return 0;
}
```

I can compile the file with standart `gcc` using these options:
`-g -O2 -m32 -Wa,--32 -Wl,-melf_i386 -pg`
And use this file with `i686-android-linux-gprof`

But I cannot use `pg` key with `i686-android-linux-gcc`, does anybody know why? And how can I use it, maybe i must use some additional libraries/compilation options in NDK rebuilding process?

Comment: Here you go: http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/wiki/Usage

Comment: It's not profiler from NDK it's handmade profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there is no `mcount` function.
I has downloaded Android Sources there is no `mcount` function, only 1 call of it so i think it's provide this error.

I found same problem at [android issues](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=37909).

Answer (score 3):

You have to add some modifications to your Android.mk:

```
#include android-ndk-profiler.mk

LOCAL_CFLAGS := -pg
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := andprof

LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
```

Refer to http://code.google.com/p/android-ndk-profiler/wiki/Usage for more step-by-step details.

**P.S.** It seems that x86 runtime simply does not contain `mcount`. Define it elsewhere in your code:

```
#if !( defined(_M_ARM) || defined(__arm__) )
   int mcount = 0;
#endif
```

Comment: Yes i know about mcount(. but I want to fix android sources without additional libraries. Maybe add mcount to android.

Comment: How? I need one decigion for different sources.

Comment: #if !( defined(_M_ARM) || defined(__arm__) )

Comment: What it is type of mcount in pg?